# Java - give a null object's field a value or declaring an object with no constructors not null

Tags: java, object, constructor, null

Feels like a super basic question, but I can't wrap my head around it.

There is a class PriceGroup, with no constructor of whom I'm making an object of.

```
class SmallPortfolio{
String id;  
// all the investments (stocks) belonging to this portfolio.
List<Investment> invList = new ArrayList<Investment>(); 
}
```

Now in a separate class, I'm creating a SmallPortfolio object named Spor.

```
//
String id = InstanceID.getTextNormalize(); //this value is taken from an element from jdom.
SmallPortfolio Spor;
Spor.id = id; 
//some code that creates a list of investments
//some code that creates a list of SmallPortfolio objects
```

In java, how do you give a null object's field a value getting by the NullPointerException?
An alternate solution would be somehow declaring a SmallPortfolio object that wasn't null.

It's a strange problem, but the test program I'm using cannot be modified and it has no constructors for SmallPortfolio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is initialize Spor:

```
SmallPortfolio Spor = new SmallPortfolio();
```

This will create a non-null object. Also, if you're going to be adding an id to it after each initialization, you may as well add that to the constructor. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you define some constructors yourself, Java will automatically create a default no-argument constructor for you. So you can write:

```
SmallPortfolio smallPort = new SmallPortfolio();
```

However, in your case, the author of the SmallPortfolio class should probably have provided an ad-hoc constructor:

```
class SmallPortfolio{
    private final String id;  
    // all the investments (stocks) belonging to this portfolio.
    private final List<Investment> investments = new ArrayList<Investment>(); 

    public SmallPortfolio(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters + methods to add / remove investments
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Spor` is never initialized:

```
SmallPortfolio Spor;
```

replace with:

```
SmallPortfolio Spor = new SmallPortfolio();
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit unclear, but if you are asking if you can assign fields or call methods on the null object, then, no, you cannot. You need to have (or make) an instance of your class.

```
 SmallPortfolio Spor = new SmallPortfolio();
 Spor.id = id;
```

The code you have shown above should not even compile, because you have not assigned a value (not even null) to `Spor`. (If you do assign `null`, you'll get a runtime nullpointer exception).

If the confusion was how to make an object when there is no constructor: In this case, there is one, because if the Java code does not specify any constructor (but only then), there is an automatic default constructor that does not need arguments.

Comment: The code given will compile if these are field declarations rather than local variable declarations.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That is correct. However, the third line (`Spor.id = id;`) cannot be used outside of a block, and while the first line (`String id = InstanceID.getTextNormalize();`) is possible for a field declaration, it also looks like it is not.

Comment: Good catch - hadn't seen that bit. (It doesn't help that the OP's terminology is *very* confused: "how do you give a null object's field a value" suggests they could do with significant lessons on variables, values, references, objects etc...)

Comment: True that. The whole first part of my answer is probably completely unrelated to what OP really wanted to ask (the default constructor).